# Rename files in python depending on file name

Tags: python

I'm creating a small script that will rename the files inside a folder depending on different criteria.  I have tried to use this, but stuck at this point

```
f = []  
for file in os.walk(outputfolder):
    f.append(file)
```

in a folder (c:\folder) i have 2 files:
file1.csv, file2.csv

how can i create a loop that goes inside the folder and do something like for each file

```
if(file1.csv.find(1) > 0)
  do this
else 
  do this
```

Thanks i have been trying for a while and i cant find a solution

Comment: Do you mean you want to look for a `1` in the *contents* of the file? I think you should read [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("path/to/folder"):
    for filename in files:
        if "1" in filename:
            do_something()
        else:
            do_something_else()
```

When you use `os.walk`, it returns a generator of the directory tree. Imagine a test directory as such:

```
C:\temp
|   \subdir
|   |   subfile1.txt
|   |   subfile2.txt
|   file1.txt
|   file2.txt
```

`list(os.walk)` will produce:

```
[("C:\\temp", ["subdir"], ["file1.txt","file2.txt"]),
 ("C:\\temp\\subdir", [], ["subfile1.txt","subfile2.txt"])]
```

That is to say, each iteration produces `root, list_of_directories_in_root, list_of_files_in_root` for each subdirectory in your original argument. We therefore iterate over `os.walk` the same way:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("path/to/folder"):
```

Now it's true you don't really care about the `root` or the `dirs`, but if you have to rename the file (or etc) you'll need at least `root` because you'll be doing `os.rename(os.path.join(root, filename), "newname.txt")`.

Answer (score 1):

`os.walk` is probably overkill unless you want to look in nested directories. `os.listdir` offers less complexity.

Your question is ambiguous on if you want to operate on the filename or the file contents. So I offer both below.:

```
import os

outputfolder = "/home/jack/code/tests"

for filename in os.listdir(outputfolder):
    # just the filename
    print filename
    if "1" in filename:
        print "\t1 is in the filename %s" % (filename)

    # the file contents
    file_path = os.path.join(outputfolder, filename)
    with open(file_path) as f:
        file_contents = f.read()
        if "1" in file_contents:
            print "\t1 is in the contents of %s" % (filename)

    print "---"
```